# Chaining member variables with side-effect with the chain not ending in a function

Tags: javascript, decorator-chaining

In the JavaScript *chaijs* testing library it is possible to chain members like this:

```
pm.expect (entry.NAME).to.be.a('string').that.is.not.empty;
```

This question is *not* about the testing library, but about the library's internal technique. I understand it works something like this: `pm.expect` is a function that returns an object that contains at least `{ to: { be: { a } } }` where `a` is another function that returns at least `{ that: { is: { not: { empty } } } }`.

The interesting thing is that `empty` apparently is not a function. If it was, I would have to call it like this: `that.is.not.empty()` (note the parentheses). So the chain ends with a member variable that is not a function.

How is it possible in JavaScript to consume that member variable to cause a side-effect? Can you show me a minimal JS snippet that allows me to end an expression with something that is not a function call (like `empty;`) and still act like it was a function call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  function expect(value) {
      return {
         get empty() { return !value.length; },
      };
  }

 expect("test").empty // false
 expect("").empty // true
```

That's done with a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get), have a look at the [ChaiJS sourcecode](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/blob/master/lib/chai/utils/addProperty.js#L38).

Answer (score 3):

> Can you show me a minimal JS snippet that allows me to end an expression with something that is not a function call (like empty;) and still act like it was a function call?

Sure. One way is to use a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get):

```js
const person = (name) => ({
  get greet()   { return `Hello ${name}!`;   },
  get dismiss() { return `Goodbye ${name}!`; }
});

console.log( person("Tyler").greet );
console.log( person("John").dismiss );
```